# 'Type is unsupported' error when trying to save Enum in DynamoDb

Tags: c#, enums, amazon-dynamodb

I have the below class that I have decorated with DynamoDb attributes:

```
[DynamoDBTable("Orders")]
public class OrderDynamoModel
{
    [DynamoDBHashKey]
    public int OrderId { get; set; }

    [DynamoDBProperty]
    public DateTime DateTimeUtc { get; set; }

    [DynamoDBProperty]
    public int TId { get; set; }

    [DynamoDBProperty]
    public OrderStatus Status { get; set; }

    [DynamoDBProperty]
    public string Order { get; set; }
}

[Flags]
public enum OrderStatus
{
    None = 0,
    Pending = 1,
    Completed = 2
}
```

When I try to save an instance of the class using DynamoDBContext.Save, I get the below error:

> Type OrderStatus is unsupported, it cannot be instantiated

When I change the type of the property from OrderStatus to int and update the code accordingly, it can save the record in DynamoDb successfully.

Any idea why I can't use the enum?

Comment: What version of the DynamodDB .Net SDK are you using?

Comment: I use AWSSDK version 2.3.55.2 and the application is using .NET 4.6.1.

Comment: That seems very old, what is the exact Nuget package you are using?

Comment: <package id="AWSSDK" version="2.3.55.2" targetFramework="net461" />

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using the old version of the AWS SDK, [version 2](https://www.nuget.org/packages/AWSSDK/), that hasn't been updated since 2016. You need to upgrade to [version 3](https://www.nuget.org/packages/AWSSDK.DynamoDBv2/), at least version 3.1.1 as that is when `enum` type support was added.

See this [AWS Blog](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/developer/dynamodb-datamodel-enum-support/) for more information.

Comment: Thanks David. Yeah I just noticed I have been using the old SDK all along.